# How do I delete the values in between the tags?

Tags: c#, winforms, tags

I want to delete the values inside the tags, how can I do that? the highlighted output is what I want to **delete** when I load the save the file.

```
 <data name="Enrolment_Exit_Verify_Message" d2p1:space="preserve"  xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
<value**>**Are you sure you want to Exit without Saving?****</value>
<comment>[Font]**Italic**[/Font][DateStamp]2015/02/01 00:00:00[/DateStamp][Comment] **this is a My awesome new comments comment.!!**[/Comment]</comment>
```

Here is how I have read in between the tags? I don't know how can I delete in-between the tags.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < oDataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string comment = oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][2].ToString();

                string font = Between(comment, "[Font]", "[/Font]");
                string datestamp = Between(comment, "[DateStamp]", "[/DateStamp]");
                string commentVal = Between(comment, "[Comment]", "[/Comment]");

                string[] row = new string[] 
                {
                    oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    oDataSet.Tables["data"].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    font, 
                    datestamp, commentVal };
                Gridview_Output.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            oDataSet.Tables.Add(oDataTable);
```

string function

```
    public string Between(string STR, string FirstString, string LastString)
    {
        string FinalString;
        int Pos1 = STR.IndexOf(FirstString) + FirstString.Length;
        int Pos2 = STR.IndexOf(LastString);
        FinalString = STR.Substring(Pos1, Pos2 - Pos1);
        return FinalString;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect your `Between` method uses `Substring`. Experiment with the `RemoveRange` instead. If that doesn't make sense to you, maybe post the code of the `Between` method as well for us to see.

Comment: Have you experimented, though?

Comment: Looking at your code again, it all seems logical. You're getting the "betweens" into the appropriate variables, and you don't even use the `comment` variable afterwards. Why and where are you trying to remove the betweens from the full string?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the regex in your `between` method if you can build up the regex. [Here is more info on the regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public string Between(string STR, string FirstString, string LastString)
{
    string regularExpressionPattern1 = @"(?:\" + FirstString + @")([^[]+)\[\/" + LastString;
    Regex regex = new Regex(regularExpressionPattern1, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(STR.ToString());
    var val = string.Empty;
    foreach (Match m in collection)
    {
        val = m.Groups[1].Value;
    }
    return val;
}
```

**Note**- Code is not tested may need to tweak for your need. Although regex expression is tested.

The above code give you the values from the tags in your case after executing the functions the variables will have the values

```
font = "**Italic**"  
datestamp = "2015/02/01 00:00:00"
commentVal = "**this is a My awesome new comments comment.!!**"
```

Then if you want it to remove from the `comment` variable just use `Replace` as

```
comment = comment.Replace(font, string.Empty);
comment = comment.Replace(datestamp, string.Empty);
comment = comment.Replace(commentVal, string.Empty);
```

At the end of it you will have the `comment` variable with removed values from that tags.

Comment: It's safe to assume that the OP is a newbie. He shouldn't be given complex regex with 0 explanation of what it is, as this is will only confuse him. At the very least, link to resources about regex, and even then I think it is good to also throw in the "easy solution".

Comment: I agree with you about it but, it is hard and more complex than `regex` to use the string function to track down what exactly you want in the string and Besides if you don't try new stuff you don't learn. I think it is good to learn new stuff.

Comment: It's great to learn new stuff. Always. But everything is bad if you get too-much of it. Here, I see too much information with too little explanation. Also, it may be more work to have it running without `regex`, but the basic string functions are still, well, the basics, and that's where you start from. OP already figured out most of it, he just guidance in how to make his `Between` method have "remove" logic rather than "substr" logic.

Comment: so i other words i must remove the way am reading the strings in between?  am confused now call all i want is to delete the values in between

Comment: You can go as the @YoryeNathan mentioned try [string methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and find the tags and replace it (That can get bit complex). Or you can use my method given in answer. And for more understanding you can read the resources online and debugg to understand how it works.

Comment: What must i put at, Match m = collection[0]; here on zero because it is breaking here

Comment: You can loop through the collection using the `foreach() ` debug it and make sure the regex pattern is matching if not let me know.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how i can do that please

Comment: now it bring this error : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Match m = collection[0];
                    return m.Groups[1].Value;

                    var val = (String)null; ;
                    foreach(Match mm in collection)
                    {
                        val = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    }
                    return val;

Comment: See the edit and now I have tested the code it is working correctly with your given input data.

Comment: did it deleted on you? i can see it is passing the values on the match but not deleting. or must i remove the coding that i modified?

Answer (score 0):

To delete the values in between you can modify the regular expression provided by @Coder of Code as shown below:

```
        string str = "[Font]**Italic**[/Font][DateStamp]2015/02/01 00:00:00[/DateStamp][Comment] **this is a My awesome new comments comment.!!**[/Comment]";
        string strPattern = @"(?:])([^[]+)\["; // Regular expression pattern to find string inside ][
        Regex rg = new Regex(strPattern);
        string newStr = rg.Replace(str, string.Format("]{0}[",string.Empty), int.MaxValue);
```

Comment: it is breaking 
string deletestr = "[Value][/Value][Font][/Font],[DateStamp][/DateStamp],[Comment][/Comment]";
                    string strPattern = @"(?:])([^[]+)\["; // Regular expression pattern to find string inside ][
                    Regex rg = new Regex(strPattern,RegexOptions.Singleline);
                    string newStr = rg.Replace(deletestr, string.Format("]{0}[", string.Empty), int.MaxValue);
                    MatchCollection collection = rg.Matches(Value.ToString());
                    Match m = collection[0]; //breaking here
                    return m.Groups[1].Value;