# What is the best way to delete between this tags <></>?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, tags

I want to delete the data in between this tags <>.

i have this function to delete in between this tags [][].

```
   string regularExpressionPattern1 = @"(?:\" + FirstString + @")([^[]+)\[\/" + LastString;
```

now i want to delete between this tags<> . i tried to modify the above pattern to this. but it doesn't work. is there any pattern i can use beside this?

```
 string regularExpressionPattern1 = @"(?:\" + FirstString + @")(<^<>+)\<\/" + LastString;
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify BBCode or Markdown?

Comment: Add some example data please

Comment: Asking the same question repeatedly will not help your cause...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451833/deleting-between-the-tags-it-is-not-deleting
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447893/how-do-i-delete-the-values-in-between-the-tags

Comment: [How Many Times will you...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/643085).... Ọ̴͖̥̲̼̦̼ͅh̵̢͖,̸͖̥̻͓̬͖̠͖ ͇̟̤ͅn͏̡̮͎͔͇͍̤̖o͘҉̥͕̲͉̘̪̪̥!̨͙̣͈̳̀!̵̙̳̰̟̱̭̙̻͡͡!̷͔̤͠!̸̡̱̗̺͉̦͡ ̵͚͖͍͎͚̙̩̞̠H͓̺̞͔̀e̝͎̲'̛̞͓̟ͅs͏̭̺ͅ ̙͙͍̞Ç̦͇͓̱͇̼̘̻o͓̤͙͍͉̟̰͖̕m̶̢̞̤͕̗i̷҉̞̭̜n͈̞̖̹̝̦̩̤̺g̷̖̠̹͙̳!̳̥̟̩̀͞!̸͎̘̗͎͓!̯͓̗̮̝